# wxMaxima: overlapping print

Tags: maxima

I'm using wxMaxima 16.12.0 (Maxima 5.39.0) and when I try to print the output, I get overlapping text.

Here's an example (please, ignore the fact the the command couldn't be correct)

***1st image***

[image: overlapping print]

Sometimes happens also with `print` and `printf` (inside a block)

***2nd image***

```
    printf(true, "Link ~d~%", i),
    print("+------------------------------------------------+"),
```

[image]

***3rd image***
[image]

But outside a block

***4th image***

[image]

This makes all the output completely unreadable, and my program heavy relies on it. I think that in the 3rd image, the problem is that there is the 2 at the denominator is causing the "shrinking" of the output.

How can I solve it? Is it my problem or Maxima's?

```
OS: Mint 18 sarah  
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.4.0-57-generic  
DE: Cinnamon 3.0.7
```

P.S. I also noticed that *sometimes*, re-running previous commands could make "readable" the following, but that always happens random

EDIT1: I noticed that the last packages that I installed are

```
libwxbase3.0-dev 
libwxgtk3.0-dev 
libwxgtk3.0-0v5
libwxbase3.0-0v5
```

Could it be that there's some kind of conflict?

EDIT2: if I cut the command, the output is "reorganized" in a decent way

[image]

become

[image]

Comment: I think you'll have to report this to the wxMaxima bug tracker: https://github.com/andrejv/wxmaxima/issues

Comment: Bounty expired, so I'll report this to the bug tracker and update this question later

Comment: Oddly enough, just changing the font settings solved the problem. (now I use `monospace 12`)

Comment: I also ran into this problem. @igng, do you want to put changing the font as an answer to help others in the future?

Answer (score 0):

As [BillThePlatypus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1518243/billtheplatypus) requested, I'll answer so that everyone will have a quick solution.

In my case, just ***changing the font*** solved the problem (i.e. no more overlapping prints), so give it a try.